# Htaccess rewrite URL with virtual directory and 2 variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, rewriting

its my URL...

```
result.php?team=arsenal&player=ospina
```

I want to like this

```
mysite.com/virtualdirectory/arsenal/ospina.html
```

I tried this code.. cant work.. Not Found

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ result.php?team=$2&player=$3 [L]
```

The requested URL /subfolder/arsenal/ospina.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 Server at localhost Port 80

Thanks for helps,
Best regards!!

Comment: can you provide more details ?  your question is not clear

Comment: You do not have any `.html` in the sample string.

Comment: did you fix your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , I assume you want to change the URI from

```
 http://www.example.com/result.php?team=arsenal&player=ospina
```

to

```
 http://www.example/subdirectory/arsenal/ospina.html
```

so this is the .htaccess that will do that for you

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^team=(.*)\&player=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdirectory/%1/%2.html [R=301]
```

you can test it with htaccess tester here 
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

---

and some useful links for documentation and learning:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

[Great Video Tutorials - Understanding Apache and htaccess](http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/understanding-apache-and-htaccess?utm_source=Tuts%20&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=suggestedcoursevideo&utm_content=sidebar&WT.mc_id=Tuts%20_website_suggestedcoursevideo_sidebar)

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.*]+)/([^\.*]+)/([^\.*]+).html$ result.php?team=$2&player=$3 [L,QSA]
```